# Overriding SignalR Contract Resolver in ASP.NET Boilerplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, aspnetboilerplate, pascalcasing

I'm having an issue where methods called in a signal R hub are returning camel cased. I see in the boilerplate documentation there is a section in signalR on how to override the default behavior

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/SignalR-Integration#pascalcase-vs-camelcase

I can't figure out how to implement this correctly. I've tried adding the below snippet to the Startup.cs before and after app.MapSignalR(). I've tried adding it to the Pre-initialize of the web module, I've added all of my assemblies; I'm out of ideas.

```
AbpSignalRContractResolver.IgnoredAssemblies.Add(typeof(MyWebModule).Assembly);
```

I'm using .NET 4.6.x, ABP Version 3.2.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the type that you want to use the default contract resolver for is in that module then you're good to go but if you're using a third part library outside of the module then you to make sure that is added to the list. From what I can tell the code that you have above should work it's just a matter of making sure the right types are added.

Comment: This is correct. The type that was returning was in another library, so things in my libraries were getting pascal cased, but the wrapper was returning in camel case. Thanks!

Comment: You just ignore third party assemblies , it will work